# Controlling CSS chunk names from a React component in Webpack 4

Tags: reactjs, webpack, code-splitting

I recently moved a Webpack configuration from version 1 to version 4.

The application is a ReactJS project which internally uses [react-loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable) to obtain code splitting.
I was able to use this also on webpack 1 thanks to the old `babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack`.

All was working perfectly, although I had no way to control chunk names with the *webpackChunkName* magic comment (the comment itself was ignored as not supported by webpack).

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import Loading from 'components/Loading';

const LoadableComponent = Loadable({
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "carousel" */'./CarouselWidget'),
  loading: Loading
});

export default (props) => (
  <LoadableComponent {...props} />
);
```

After migrating to version 4 I gained also the chunk naming feature and additional split points as some of the subcomponents loaded asynchronously with `react-loadable` were importing SASS resources:

```jsx
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss';

import React, { PureComponent, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class CarouselWidget extends Component {
```

On webpack 1 those resources were merged in the main CSS bundle, while on version 4 they are extracted as separate resource.

This is amazing and working smoothly, but I didn't find a way to customize CSS names generated by those chunks, as I get something like `6.927654d0493ed4acf802.css`.

In my webpack config I'm using custom CSS and chunk names:

```jsx
  get cssFilename() {
    return `[name]-${appVersion}.css`;
  }

  get chunkFilename() {
    return 'something-[name]-[chunkhash].chunk.js';
  }
```

This configuration if working properly for JS chunks and main CSS filenames, but not taken by SCSS above.

What I'm missing? There's a way to customize those CSS chunks?
I also tried some additional plugins, like `babel-plugin-universal-import` with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

So the problem was in an external plugin I did't mentioned: the *MiniCssExtractPlugin* configuration:

```js
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: this.cssFilename,
      chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].css'
    }),
```

Replacing `[id].[hash].css` with `[name]-[id].[hash].css` fixed the issue.